# I have to fetch more than 5000 record from db. My query is taking time about 3 minute. How I can improve my code performance

Tags: spring, resultset, jdbctemplate

I am using spring jdbc template to connect to the oracle database. I am using rowmapper to map my query resultset to java object. It this is taking time. Please suggest on this. How I can improve perfromance.

```
public class DCLMDRMLombardMapper implements RowMapper<MDRMData> {
    public MDRMData mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        MDRMData mdrmData = new MDRMData(
                resultSet.getString("NAME"),
                resultSet.getString("SCHED_NM"),
                resultSet.getInt("SEQ"),
                resultSet.getString("AMOUNT") ,
                resultSet.getInt("RPT_DT_ID"),
                resultSet.getString("RECORD_ID")`strong text`
                );
        LOGGER.debug("Return from mapper  " + mdrmData.toString());
        return mdrmData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 5000 records is still "nothing" and should not take 3 minutes, unless you are having some seriously inefficient SQL.
2. You will need to put your SQL query AND your table design AND your rowmapper here for us to give you a better answer.

Comment: I cannot put my code here bcs of company restriction. I am using spring jdbc using rowmapper to map resultset tojava object it this is taking time to process 5000 records. I am fetching entire data at one go and mapping to java object

Comment: The question is: Is your SQL slow or your RowMapper. Processing 5000 records in "Java" in a RowMapper should take no time, UNLESS you do something crazy with every record.

Comment: when I execute in sql developer the query is get executed in secs. but when i connect to java code the query its taking time

Comment: using              queryOutputList = namedparamjdbcTemplate.query(query, mapSqlParameterSource, new MultiValueMDRMMapper());

Comment: This is your main problem. A query returning 5000 records shouldn't take "seconds" or "minutes". And unless we know what your RowMapper, i.e. your MultiValueMDRMMapper  is doing, we can't really help.

Comment: Added rowmapper

Comment: Your rowmapper looks just fine, so the problem will be your SQL query.

Comment: but in sql developer when i run query it will run seconds thers is not much complex logic using only one inner join

Comment: SELECT distinct
   a.column 1  ,
   b.column 1,
    b.column 2,
   b.column 3,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(        PARTITION BY a.column 1        ORDER BY            b.column 1 asc    )  seq,
a.column 1  ,b.column 4
FROM
    table1 a
    inner join
  ( select column 1, column 2,column 3,column 4
FROM
    table2 b
WHERE
    AND column 2 = 'FRY14Q B'
    AND column 3 = 20191231
    ) b 
on
a.column 1=b.column 1  order by seq;

Comment: using this above simple query which fetches 5000 records not sure what going wrong its taking long time to fetch result. when i connect to my java code

Comment: when i executed                  int resultCount = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query1, mapSqlParameterSource, Integer.class);

Comment: I have queried select count (*) from table 1 which fetches me 24000 records. It just got executed in  0.11 minutes. It seems the problem is only when I am using rowmapper to map query result set to java  object.  where it try to map each row of the result set. Please suggest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210807/discussion-between-pri-and-marco-behler).

Comment: Hi, Do you have any suggestion on this.